# Oracle How to make SELECT INSIDE A SELECT work?

Tags: oracle, select

Just wondering why the following select isn't working:

```
 SELECT 
    A.FIELD1
     , (SELECT PCN FROM (select B.PRIORITY, B.PCN 
                        from
                        TABLE2 B 
                        WHERE B.CUST= A.CUST 
                        ORDER BY B.PRIORITY) 
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS PCN 
  FROM TABLE1 A;
```

> ERROR at line 2: ORA-00904: "A"."CUST": invalid identifier

Important to mention:

- TABLE1 has as fields FIELD1, CUST.
- TABLE2 has as fields PCN, PRIORITY, CUST.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest inline selects (more than one level) without losing the ability of the inner nested selects being able to reference the parent block. So your query on TABLE2 cannot see the columns from TABLE1 because of this nesting.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.field1,
       pcn.pcn
  FROM table1 a,
       (SELECT b.cust,
               b.priority,
               b.pcn,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.cust ORDER BY b.priority DESC) seq
          FROM table2 b) pcn
 WHERE a.cust = pcn.cust(+)
   AND pcn.seq(+) = 1
```

That will work well for report queries. If you end up adding a filter on a specific customer, then you would be better off using OUTER APPLY if you have a recent-enough version of Oracle that supports that.

Comment: Note that there are several versions of Oracle that did allow this behavior, even though it's against the ANSI standard and the documentation. So it's possible that the OP's query worked in an old version and started failing after an upgrade. There are even official patches to restore the incorrect behavior, but I agree with you that rewriting the query is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your query shouldn't give you that error message, on when you remove the outer qiery this would happen

```
CREATE tABLE TABLE1  (FIELD1 int, CUST int)
```

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(1,1)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (PCN int, PRIORITY int, CUST int)
```

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES (1,1,1)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
SELECT 
    A.FIELD1
     , (SELECT PCN FROM (select B.PRIORITY, B.PCN 
                        from
                        TABLE2 B 
                        WHERE B.CUST= A.CUST 
                        ORDER BY B.PRIORITY) 
         WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS PCN 
  FROM TABLE1 A;
```

| FIELD1 | PCN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3z5VS0Bk)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT 
A.FIELD1
 , (SELECT B.PCN 
                    from
                    TABLE2 B 
                    WHERE B.CUST= A.CUST 
                    ORDER BY B.PRIORITY
     FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) AS PCN 
FROM TABLE1 A;
```

FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY gets you the first ordered record.  Works on 12c and up and supports nesting, and no 2nd subquery needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option might be a CTE.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  table1 (field1, cust) as
  3    (select 1, 100 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 200 from dual
  5    ),
  6  table2 (pcn, priority, cust) as
  7    (select 10, 1, 100 from dual union all
  8     select 20, 2, 100 from dual union all
  9     select 30, 1, 200 from dual
 10    ),
```

Query begins here. Rank rows by priority, and then fetch the ones that rank as the highest (line #20):

```
 11  temp as
 12    (select a.field1,
 13         b.pcn,
 14         rank() over (partition by a.field1 order by b.priority desc) rnk
 15     from table1 a join table2 b on a.cust = b.cust
 16    )
 17  select field1,
 18         pcn
 19  from temp
 20  where rnk = 1;

    FIELD1        PCN
---------- ----------
         1         20
         2         30

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `first` aggregate function to achieve the same (assuming that you have completely deterministic `order by`) functionality without nested subquery:

> ```
> select
>   a.field1
>   , (
>     select max(b.pcn) keep(dense_rank first order by b.priority)
>     from table2 b
>     where b.cust = a.cust
>   ) as pcn
> from table1 a
> ```

which for this sample data

```
insert into table1 values(1,1);
insert into table1 values(2,2);
insert into table2 values(1,1,1);
insert into table2 values(2,2,1)
```

returns

| FIELD1 | PCN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | (null) |

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b601e/1)